# Excel IF Statements & Formulas

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am importing into excel timestamps in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss` into column A of a new spreadsheet.  I am trying to calculate the difference between two times.

So in column B I have the formula `=RIGHT(A1,6)` which gets the `SS.sss` value.  In Column C I am taking the values away from each other - `=B2-B1`.  This correctly calculates the gap between the two values.

What I want to do now, is create an IF statement `=IF(C2<>0.02,"","Error")`, to determine if the time gap is not the value is it supposed to be.

The problem is, that this IF statement always is evaluated as `Error` instead of the blank cell, even if the value in column C is 0.02.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: try this one: `=IF(INT(100*C2)/100<>0.02,"","Error")` . Most likely that your `C2` contain something like `0.0199` and dispays like `0.02`. (You can see it by changing [decimal places](http://www.originlab.com/www/helponline/origin/en/mergedprojects/tutorial/images/Working_with_Excel/Tutorials81_Working_with_Excel_001.png))

Comment: Sorry, that one didn't work.  I have a feeling it is because of the formulas, but I've tried the `=VALUE()` function and it's still not worked.

Comment: Try to increase [decimal places](http://www.originlab.com/www/helponline/origin/en/mergedprojects/tutorial/images/Working_with_Excel/Tutorials81_Working_with_Excel_001.png)

Comment: what about `=IF(ROUND(C2,2)<>0.02,"","Error")` ?

Comment: Sadly, again no luck with that one either!

Comment: Hang on, wait, I can't reproduce this as you describe. Your '<>' means NOT EQUAL, right? So you are saying if C2 DOES NOT EQUAL 0.02, leave the cell empty; otherwise (C2 DOES EQUAL 0.02) display "Error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're comparing *text* `0.02` with *value* `0.02`? Try:

```
=IF(VALUE(C2)<>0.02,"","Error")
```

Comment: +1 - the `RIGHT` function returns TEXT, and the original `IF` statement was expecting a number

Answer (score 0):

The test in =IF(C2<>0.02,"","Error") with C2=0.02 evaluates to FALSE (ie C2 DOES equal 0.02), so 'of course' the third parameter is returned. I suspect you may want `=IF(C2=0.02,"","Error")`.